# Make equally spaced tick marks for non-linear x-axis values in a base r plot

Tags: r, spacing

The values I want for my x-axis are not linear, but I would like them to be equally spaced apart. Is there a way to do this?

Here's what I did, but it didn't show up as equally spaced

```
axis(1, c(4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,40,56,80), las=1)
```

[image: this is what my plot currently looks like]

[image: this is one of my data tables]

Comment: This is easier in `ggplot()` but for base R, would it be possible to make your x variable a factor with the levels `c("4", "8", "12", "16", "20", "24", "28", "32", "40", "56", "80")`, (but values of `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)`) and plot it like that?

Comment: Please show the data and the code you used to create your plot. It's easier to create an answer based on your efforts.